# Autocomplete with Ajax returns No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I am trying to implement an autocomplete on my textbox with data that comes from a web method. The webmethod works on the browser like:

```
http://localhost/psa/DesktopModules/PsaMain/API/ModuleTask/GetIssuers?SearchString=e
```

and these are the results:

```
[{"IssuerID":1,"Name":"test tester","ChequeAccountNumber":"12345678","CurrencyCode":"EUR"}]
```

Now, I am trying to add on the textbox the Name data from the response but I'm getting an error in the function below:

```
{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost/psa/DesktopModules/PsaMain/API/ModuleTask/GetIssuers?{ 'SearchString': 'e'}'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'ModuleTask' that matches the request."}
```

Below, my AJAX call seems to fail for a reason, which I believe comes from passing wrongly the parameters. I do not have experience with ajax so far, so your input will be great.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
        $("[id$=TextBox1]").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<%=ResolveUrl("http://localhost/psa/DesktopModules/PsaMain/API/ModuleTask/GetIssuers")%>',
                    data: "{ 'SearchString': '" + request.term + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "GET",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.split('-')[0],
                                val: item.split('-')[1]
                            }
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function (e, i) {
                $("[id$=hfIssuerID]").val(i.item.val);
            },
            minLength: 1
        });
    });
 </script>
```

My web method:

```
public class ModuleTaskController : DnnApiController
{
[AllowAnonymous()]
[HttpGet()]
public HttpResponseMessage GetIssuers(string SearchString)
{
    try {
        List<Issuers> listIssuers = new List<Issuers>();
        IssuersController ic = new IssuersController();
        listIssuers = ic.GetIssuers(10, SearchString);
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, listIssuers.ToJson);

    } catch (Exception exc) {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, exc);
    }
}
}
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

```
  $(function () {
        $("[id$=TextBox1]").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                var qstring = '?' + jQuery.param({ 'SearchString': request.term });
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<%=ResolveUrl("http://localhost/psa/DesktopModules/PsaMain/API/ModuleTask/GetIssuers")%>' + qstring,
                    type: "GET",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.split('-')[0],
                                val: item.split('-')[1]
                            }
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function (e, i) {
                $("[id$=hfIssuerID]").val(i.item.val);
            },
            minLength: 1
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your web method is a `GET` and accepts a `querystring` yet your `Ajax` call is trying to pass a `JSON` object, which is getting appended to the end of your url. You can see this by reading what the `URL` actually is, in the error message

There are a bunch of different things you can do. This is just one.

```
 // turn your search object into querystring
var qstring = '?'+ jQuery.param({ 'SearchString': request.term});
 // append this querystring to the end of your url
$.ajax({
        url: '<%=ResolveUrl("http://localhost/psa/DesktopModules/PsaMain/API/ModuleTask/GetIssuers")%>' + qstring ,
        // remove data and datatype
        type: "GET",
        //... etc
```

Also in this case, it doesn't look like you need the ResolveUrl.

Perhaps try your URL as:

`url:'http://localhost/psa/DesktopModules/PsaMain/API/ModuleTask/GetIssuers' + qstring;`

Comment: your answer fixes my original problem. However, now the process does not go into the 'success' part, but neither the failure. When I debug (beginner level of debugging) the process goes to the ajax sources and never comes back. Any ideas?

Comment: Check the inspector of your browser. E.G if it's chrome, press F12 - see if you have any JS errors. it's very possible there is a small syntax error with your edit (or my code).

Comment: I'm lost... want to connect via teamviewer?

Comment: No, sorry. Paste your new code as an edit to your question

Comment: pasted above in my question

Comment: Code looks ok. You need to look at your browsers developer tools to find any error in your console. Google it if you're not sure what I mean (typically, pressing F12 while viewing your browser will bring this up) - side note, you don't need to use resolveUrl in this case. see my edit

Comment: Same result. When I mentioned earlier that code disappears somewhere i was referring to the jquery-ui.js  in this function:  _delay: function( handler, delay ) {
  function handlerProxy() {
   return ( typeof handler === "string" ? instance[ handler ] : handler )
    .apply( instance, arguments );
  }

Comment: returnValue under ProxiePrototype[prop]</<jquery-ui.js:420 is undefined

Comment: Your answer was correct. I displayed the results via an alert(data) just right below the 'success'. So my problem now is displaying the results on the textbox. I have asked another question if you are interested to have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088485/autocomplete-jquery-not-displaying-results