# Autocomplete JQuery not displaying results

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to display the results on my `autocomplete textbox` but I'm not sure how to return the results from the ajax call, or I'm not sure why it fails to display them. The data is displayed on my `Alert(data)` like this:

```
[{"IssuerID":1,"Name":"tester test","ChequeAccountNumber":"12345678","CurrencyCode":"EUR"},{"IssuerID":3,"Name":"Taryn","ChequeAccountNumber":"1115555","CurrencyCode":"GBP"}]
```

I believe the problem is on the `response($.map(data.d, function (item)` block because I'm not sure what values to insert there (id or val or something else), or how to declare the variables. 
Any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                var qstring = '?' + jQuery.param({ 'SearchString': request.term });
                $.ajax({
                    url:'http://localhost/psa/DesktopModules/PsaMain/API/ModuleTask/GetIssuers' + qstring,
                    type: "GET",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                id: item.issuerid, //here might be the problem
                                val: item.name
                            }
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

html:

```
<div class="ui-widgetx">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

**Edit**

After I modified my 'success' code, I can see the dropdown menu with empty items:

```
success: function (result) {
    var parsed = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
    myArray = parsed.map(function (e) {
        return { label: e.Name, value: e.IssuerID };
    });
    response($.map(myArray, function (item) {
        return { label: item.Name, value: item.IssuerID };
    }))
},
```

Any ideas how to get the correct items on the dropdown list of JQuery from my array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery UI Autocomplete widget requires the response to be an array of objects with `label` and `value` keys. If that's the autocompleter your using, you'll need to change your map to:

```
response($.map(data, function(item) {
  return { label: item.Name, value: item.IssuerID }
});
```

**Edit**

You can change your edited code to this:

```
success: function (result) {
    var parsed = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
    var myArray = parsed.map(function (e) {
        return { label: e.Name, value: e.IssuerID };
    });
    response(myArray);
},
```

You only need to map the parsed JSON once, if you try to map it again the property names will be different, which is why you got an array of empty objects.

Comment: Are you getting the capitalization right on `Name` and `IssuerID`?

Comment: @yes, maybe the problem is because it's a json array?

Comment: `$.map` should work properly with a JSON array. I'm not sure what the problem could be.

Comment: I have modified the code and now I'm getting something. Could you please have a look at my edit?

Comment: Your edit works. The problem was the json array of objects. The downvoters of my question did not understand the problem. Could you upvote my question please as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.Issuerid,
                                value: item.Name
                            }
                        }))
                    },
```

Comment: Try to do a console.log in your response function before return put console.log(item.issuerid) or alert(item.issuerid)

Comment: And try to change label: item.issuerid, //here might be the problem
                                value: item.name

Comment: did you try the alert before return??

Comment: Ok i saw it´s label: item.Issuerid and value: item.Name

Comment: the alert before return never displays. Only before response is shown

Comment: I have modified the code and now I'm getting something. Could you please have a look at my edit?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and a debugging "alert" similar/identical to the one you have was killing it:

> success: function (data) {
> alert(data);

Neglected to check whether console.log acts similarly.